# embed a java code editor with limited scope in a swing application?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, ide

Here's what I want to do.  I want to store code objects in my hibernate driven java swing application.  I want to allow the user to create code objects that can affect the data with a limited scope, like in a function with only access to members of that member's class.  I'd even really like to have a full on little ide (though scaled down with all the irrelevencies hidden) in there which would allow auto-completion and have a button to compile and check, then have all that wrapped so I can drop the thing in my database and schedule it's execution.

Anyone have a good idea, know a good component or way to use eclipse or some such to accomplish this without having a roll out a solution myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use Eclipse RCP editor, it has lots of functionality available for reuse. e.g. text highlighting, pair constructions highlighting, text hovers, completion assist, etc.
its a lot more powerful, but a lot heavier. and RCP is not only editor...

Comment: I am so using that for my next application, that's exactly what I want to do.  Then I have access to other eclipse plugins, perfecto!  Perfect answer!

Answer (score 1):

To achieve code highlighting and some *simple* auto complete functionality it would be worth looking at the [jsyntaxpane](http://code.google.com/p/jsyntaxpane/) component.

It's pretty simple and easy to use but you're not going to get the compile functionality from that.

Comment: That looks like a neat project, it might do for what I want.  Thanks!